# Where are the structured data meta tags coming from in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, meta, structured-data

I have currently taken maintenance of a WordPress site. I see structured data being written in each of the pages.

I can't figure out where all this data comes from. There's no plugin or anything similar.

There's plenty of `meta` `og` tags and no trace of this code generation.

You can check this sample site:
http://www.clinicadentalanfruns.com/tratamientos/

Comment: It could be inside the head.php file in the template.

Comment: You also have structured data in JSON-LD  (using Schema.org). Do you also wonder about this or only about the OGP meta tags?

Comment: Why not search your theme and plugin files for them?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answers. Yes i am wondering about all structured data. There is nothing generating it...